# Does 'default=...' in Django model fields set 'blank=True' by default?

Tags: python, django

I have a question for the Django model field when applying the `default` setting. My problem is as follows:

```
# Model description
class aa(models.Model):
    a = models.FloatField(default=1)
    b = models.FloatField()
```

When inserting an entry into the database, I apply the following functions to do the validation without any error:

```
data = {'b': 1.1} # Just for demo...
p = aa(**data)
p.full_clean()
p.save()
```

Here is the problem, is the case that when I set the `default` value for a field, the `blank` is automatically set to `True`?

P.S. I know what are the differences between `null` and `blank`, I just want to figure out the issues related to the `default`.

Comment: Question title edited for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put `default` on a model field, actually it is not setting `blank = True` . When you initialize a `Model` like

```
instance = ModelClass(**field_data)
```

django will check for all fields and if the field value is not there, then it will try checkin default value by calling `get_default()` method (look for default value) on `Field` class.

Comment: So in this case, with the default values, the model instance will set all fields to certain values before the `full_clean` is executed?

Comment: Yup.You can check by `instance = ModelClass(**field_data); print instance.field` , field which have default value.

Comment: Thus is the case that the common usage of `default`, `blank`, and `null` with respect to a certain model field either sets `default=...` or the combination of `blank=...` and `null=...` without setting both `default` and `blank` values?

Answer (score 1):

Django model fields default to required unless you specify `blank=True` and/or `null=True`. In your example, the model validates because you have defaulted `a` to 1 and set `b` to 1.1. Neither field is blank, so you're not encountering a situation that hits the question you're asking.

Try changing `data = {'b': 1.1}` to `data = {'a': 1.1}` and see what happens - you should get a field validation error.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Django always do that. If you don't need that feature simple make it set `blank = False`